# Using XPath to get text within a <td> cell using python

Tags: python, html, xpath, web, web-crawler

I am currently learning how to use XPath to extract information from an HTML document. I am using python and have had no trouble getting values of things like the title of a webpage, but when I try to get the text of a particular cell in a table, I simply get an empty value returned.

Here is my code, I used chrome to copy the XPath of the table cell I want to get the value from.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_Games_host_cities')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will get the cell text:
location = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/text()')

print('Location: ', location)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

poked around a bit.

Try: 
`tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tr/td[3]/text()')`

I think the content is a bit different on a webpage rendered in Chrome vs what was returned by requests. (i.e. textbody wasn't needed, and specifying tr[1] was yielding empty result. FYI. The xpath you provided checked out and worked fine in chrome.

See Andersson's answer below as well, but basically, tbody may be added by browser, best not to use it in path

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies from both of you. Would you mind showing me an example for the tree.xpath for if I just wanted to return one single row's specific column, rather than all the values in that column? For example, if I wanted to only print 'Europe' from that first row. Thanks again!!

Comment: Sure no problem. try ```tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]//tr[1]/td[3]/text()')```

Note: how the ```//``` is shortcut for self or decendant, then we go to the second tr index, and then into the td

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `tbody` tag in your XPath expressions as it might be ignored by developer and added by browser while page rendering. You can try below XPath to get required values:

```
location = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]//tr[not(parent::thead)]/td[3]/text()')
```

The output is

```
Location:  ['Europe', 'Europe', 'North America', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', '
Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'North America', 'North America
', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Asia', '\nEurope', 'Asia', '\nEurope', 'Europe', 'Europe
', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Oceania', '\nEurope', 'Nor
th America', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'North America', 'Asia', 'Eur
ope', 'Europe', 'North America', 'North America', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'North Ame
rica', 'North America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'North America', '
Asia', 'Oceania', 'North America', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'North America',
'Europe', 'Europe', 'South America', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'North Am
erica']
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the tbody information. Makes total sense re: my answer above. :) I think I always just used the // to get decendents so I never noticed it.